# HTML/CSS overlaying transparent boxes

Tags: html, css, overlay, transparent

I'm trying to overlay a transparent box that spans the width of the page at the navigation bar, and then one that spans the entire height of the page. I can get the horizontal bar in, but when I do I can't lower it from the top of the page without lowering all other content as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>

<head> 
         <title>Welcome Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="topbar">
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="images/WelcomeHomeLogo.png"> </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="toolbar">
            <li id="left"><a href="lol.html"> About Us </a></li>
            <li id="left"> <a href=""> Volunteer </a></li>
            <li id="left"><a href=""> Donate </a></li>
            <li id="left"><a href="lol.html"> Contact Us </a></li>
            <li id="left"><a href="lol.html"> Blog </a></li>
            <li id="right"><a href="lol.html"> Events </a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image:url("../images/thewood.jpeg");
background-size: cover;
}

#container{
background-color:#ffffff;
width: 69%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
opacity:0.7234;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
height: 950px;
  }

#topbar{
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
opacity:0.7234;
width: 100%;
background-color:#ffffff;
height:150px;
 }

li{
float: left;
list-style: none;
display: inline;
color: black;
font-size: 170%;
padding-right:48px;
margin-top: 105px;
}

#logo{
float:left;
margin-top:40px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-left:8px;
}

ul{
display: inline;
}

#right{
float: right;
padding-left:none;
}

a:link {text-decoration:none;color:black;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;color:black;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none;color: black;}
a:active (text-decoration:none;color:black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways, but this will get you where you need to be with minimal change to your current set-up.

Make #topbar a separate element (not a container for #container) like so:

```
<div id="topbar"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
```

and then adjuste the margins CSS for #topbar and #container accordingly

```
#container {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width: 69%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity:0.7234;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    height: 980px;
    margin-top: -180px; /*Push back to top of page (height of #topbar + 30px)*/
}
#topbar {
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:0.7234;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:150px;
    margin-top: 30px; /*Move it down*/
}
```